# Not able to zoom in on Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have created a Google Chart that visualises the outside temperature at my house. The amount of data keeps growing, so the chart gets unreadable in a few days ;-)
I want to be able to zoom in on the x-axis, but I can't get it to work with the `explorer` option.
I've tried:

```
explorer: { actions: ["dragToZoom", "rightClickToReset"], 
            maxZoomIn: 0.2,
            maxZoomOut: 1.0,
            zoomDelta: 10,
            axis: "horizontal",
            keepInBounds: true
          },
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I've got so far:
https://codepen.io/wtrdk/pen/wpGVVW or https://weather.wtrdk.nl/test.html

UPDATE:
I've added the following code to create a continuous axis, but I still can't zoom in...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([
    // first column is calculated
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        // convert string to date
        return new Date(dt.getValue(row, 0));
      },
      label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    // just use index # for second column
    1
     ]);
```

Comment: `explorer` only works with continuous axes (such as numbers or dates) -- the codepen has a discrete axis (string values)

Comment: Please see my update. I’ve converted to continuous but I’m still not able to zoom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the current library...

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

`jsapi` is out of date, according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  $.get(
    "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://weather.wtrdk.nl/temperature.csv",
    function(csvString) {
      // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
      var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {
        onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar
      });

      // this new DataTable object holds all the data
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
      
       var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([
    // first column is calculated
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        // convert string to date
        return new Date(dt.getValue(row, 0));
      },
      label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    // just use index # for second column
    1
     ]);


      var temperature = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: "AreaChart",
        containerId: "temperature",
        dataTable: view,
        options: {
          height: 400,
          explorer: {
            actions: ["dragToZoom", "rightClickToReset"],
            //axis: "horizontal",
            //keepInBounds: true
          },
          animation: { duration: 2000, easing: "out", startup: true },
          title: "Temperature",
          titleTextStyle: { color: "grey", fontSize: 11 },
          legend: { textStyle: { color: "grey", fontSize: 11 } },
          backgroundColor: { fill: "transparent" },
          colors: ["#e39c3a"],
          hAxis: {
            textStyle: {
              color: "grey",
              fontSize: 11
            },
            //format: 'datetime',
          },
          vAxis: {
            title: "°C",
            titleTextStyle: {
              color: "grey",
              fontSize: 22
            },
            textStyle: {
              color: "grey",
              fontSize: 11
            }
          }
        }
      });
      temperature.draw();
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://weather.wtrdk.nl/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
<body bgcolor="#282B30">
  <div id="temperature"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I'm looking for!
Happy holidays! ;-)

Comment: looks like the csv file is missing now